# Why the consequence of AES encryption has huge difference between w/ C# and w/ OpenSSL C++?

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, openssl

I tried to `AES` encryption & decryption w/ `C++ w/OpenSSL` and `C#`,so far I have written the code  and I found a problem,it was the consequence of encryption had huge difference between `C#` and `C++ w/OpenSSL` even I used the same Key and IV and same mode, so far I have no idea why it was that and  I didn't test the decryption yet,I showed my code

Here is my C# code these was exactly copied from `MSDN`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.8

```
     public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
     {
        byte[] Key = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Aa123!@#Aa123!@#Aa123!@#");

        byte[] IV = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Qwer1234Qwer1234");
        // Check arguments. 
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
        byte[] encrypted;

        // Create an AesCryptoServiceProvider object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {

            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;
            aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.


        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.




        string encryptedstr = Base64Encode(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted));
        return encryptedstr;

    }






class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        LoginparModels loginmodel = new LoginparModels();

        loginmodel.Mdpass = Globalvariable.CalculateMD5Hash("testrj");
        loginmodel.Curno = "01";

        DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(LoginparModels));
        MemoryStream msObj = new MemoryStream();
        js.WriteObject(msObj, loginmodel);
        msObj.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(msObj);


        string json = sr.ReadToEnd();

        string mydata=Cyptodecrypt.Encrypt(json);
    }
```

The plain text was:

```
{"Curno":"01","Mdpass":"140154FC6134C9B9FAF77B3F348DEE03"}
```

The consequence of mydata was:

```
B++/vQ4fB++/ve+/ve+/vXB3CdSe77+9YE9E77+977+9STpsa++/vRM+77+977+977+9RRotcRRkXe+/vSbvv70H77+9HGYM77+977+9Gx1t77+906hn77+977+977+977+977+9PO+/ve+/vWBf
```

Here is my `C++ w/ OpenSSL`

```
static const std::string base64_chars =
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"0123456789+/";


static inline bool is_base64(unsigned char c) {
   return (isalnum(c) || (c == '+') || (c == '/'));
}

std::string base64_encode(unsigned char const* bytes_to_encode, unsigned int in_len) {
   std::string ret;
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   unsigned char char_array_3[3];
   unsigned char char_array_4[4];

   while (in_len--) {
     char_array_3[i++] = *(bytes_to_encode++);
       if (i == 3) {
        char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
        char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
        char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
        char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 0x3f;

        for (i = 0; (i <4); i++)
            ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[i]];
        i = 0;
     }
  }

  if (i)
  {
    for (j = i; j < 3; j++)
        char_array_3[j] = '\0';

    char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
    char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
    char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);

    for (j = 0; (j < i + 1); j++)
        ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[j]];

    while ((i++ < 3))
        ret += '=';

 }

   return ret;

}



int encryptdate(string plaindatas, string & encryptedatas)
{



const unsigned char iv[16] = { 'Q', 'w', 'e', 'r', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'Q', 'w', 'e', 'r', '1', '2', '3', '4' };

const unsigned char key[24] = { 'A', 'a', '1', '2', '3', '!', '@', '#', 'A', 'a', '1', '2', '3', '!', '@', '#', 'A', 'a', '1', '2', '3', '!', '@', '#' };

const unsigned char * in = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *> (plaindatas.c_str());



int written = 0, temp;
unsigned char * outbuf = new unsigned char[plaindatas.length() + 1];
int in_len = plaindatas.length();

EVP_CIPHER_CTX  *ctx;
if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
{
    string errstr = ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
    errstr = "ERROR: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new failed. OpenSSL error:" + errstr;
    write_text_to_log_file(errstr);
    return -1;
}

if (1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
{
    string errstr = ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
    errstr = "ERROR: EVP_EncryptInit_ex failed. OpenSSL error:" + errstr;
    write_text_to_log_file(errstr);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
    return -1;
}


EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, EVP_PADDING_PKCS7);

if (1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &temp, in, in_len))
{
    string errstr = ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
    errstr = "ERROR: EVP_EncryptUpdate failed. OpenSSL error:" + errstr;
    write_text_to_log_file(errstr);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
    return -1;
}

written = temp;

if (1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf + temp, &temp))
{
    string errstr = ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
    errstr = "ERROR: EVP_EncryptFinal_ex failed. OpenSSL error:" + errstr;
    write_text_to_log_file(errstr);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
    return -1;
}

written += temp;

//EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);

encryptedatas = base64_encode(outbuf, written);
return 0;
}



 int main()
 {
    json::value obj;


    valueobj[L"Mdpass"] = json::value::string(passwordw);
    valueobj[L"Curno"] = json::value::string(curnow);
    wstring loginjsonparmjson = valueobj.serialize();
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt <wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>> converter(new std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>("zh_CN.gb18030"));
    std::string plaintext = converter.to_bytes(loginjsonparmjson);
    std::string chipertext;

     int result = encryptdate(plaintext, chipertext);
 }
```

The plaintext was:

```
{"Curno":"01","Mdpass":"140154fc6134c9b9faf77b3f348dee03"}
```

The consequence was:

```
Wu07vZHFHw8tkQagxwj9YtriMk/vl1R3OS+o1GMODPHv9w4aw8GwxknKL7QsH9gXbFf62cBkffHkjv6w2YxeWQ==
```

Comment: "Base64Encode(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted))" - why the GetString? Why not just Base64Encode(encrypted)?

Comment: Like Rup said - also remove the StreamWriter. Base64 is to encode a byte array as string, not encoding a string as another string.